# PPA issues unable to update app store

Tags: ppa

my app store wont update because of this error 'E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file'

i tried this

sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release

Error: need a single repository as argument

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It's saying that particular PPA doesn't yet support Juno (Bionic/18.04).

Remove the files `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine*` and you should be able to update again.